# Rank on every change of value in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame like this (data frame reproducible)

```
dt <- read.table(text = "Email  Level
                         abc    Level_6
                         abc    Level_6
                         abc    Level_6
                         abc    Level_6
                         abc    Level_6
                         xyz    Level_5
                         xyz    Level_5
                         xyz    Level_2
                         xyz    Level_2
                         xyz    Level_3
                         pqr    Level_1
                         pqr    Level_4
                         pqr    Level_5
                         pqr    Level_5
                         pqr    Level_1", header = T)

> dt
   Email   Level
1    abc Level_6
2    abc Level_6
3    abc Level_6
4    abc Level_6
5    abc Level_6
6    xyz Level_5
7    xyz Level_5
8    xyz Level_2
9    xyz Level_2
10   xyz Level_3
11   pqr Level_1
12   pqr Level_4
13   pqr Level_5
14   pqr Level_5
15   pqr Level_1
```

I want to add a new column Rank, where rank starts from 1, and changes only when there is change in column Level, per Email id. 
If the value does not change Rank will continue with the previous value

**Hence expected output is**

```
> dt_expected
    Email   Level Rank
1    abc  Level_6    1
2    abc  Level_6    1
3    abc  Level_6    1
4    abc  Level_6    1
5    abc  Level_6    1

6    xyz  Level_5    1
7    xyz  Level_5    1
8    xyz  Level_2    2
9    xyz  Level_2    2
10   xyz  Level_3    3

11   pqr  Level_1    1
12   pqr  Level_4    2
13   pqr  Level_5    3
14   pqr  Level_5    3
15   pqr  Level_1    4
```

How can I achieve this in data table?

Comment: @Ronak I am not sure if this the same question, please check it. Rank will change only when the value of level changes, this is not the same question

Comment: It is not clear why `Level_5` is not changing to `Rank`

Comment: it is because it started for new user xyz, the ranking is as per Email

Comment: Try this `library(dplyr);dt %>% group_by(Email) %>% mutate(Rank = match(Level, unique(Level)))`

Comment: @akrun - any data table solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'Email' and get the run-length-id of the 'Level' column that increments value by checking the adjacent elements of the column

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(Email) %>%
   mutate(Rank = rleid(Level))
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   Email [3]
#   Email Level    Rank
#   <fct> <fct>   <int>
# 1 abc   Level_6     1
# 2 abc   Level_6     1
# 3 abc   Level_6     1
# 4 abc   Level_6     1
# 5 abc   Level_6     1
# 6 xyz   Level_5     1
# 7 xyz   Level_5     1
# 8 xyz   Level_2     2
# 9 xyz   Level_2     2
#10 xyz   Level_3     3
#11 pqr   Level_1     1
#12 pqr   Level_4     2
#13 pqr   Level_5     3
#14 pqr   Level_5     3
#15 pqr   Level_1     4
```

---

Or check the values with the next value of 'Level' create a logical index and get the cumulative sum

```
dt %>%
  group_by(Email) %>%
  mutate(Rank = 1 + cumsum(Level != lag(Level, default = first(Level))) )
```

---

or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, Rank := rleid(Level), Email]
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
dt$Rank <- with(dt, as.integer(ave(as.character(Level), Email, 
      FUN = function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths)))))
```

Comment: I think it works but fails when one of the level values repeat. check for user pqr. The last level is same as first, however then the rank should have been 4 not 1. It fails there

Comment: @Hardikgupta  Isn't it `1 2 3 3 4` as in expected

Comment: I have edited the question, I apologise. Can you please check the new dt values

Comment: for user pqr, level is 1, 4, 5, 5, 1 hence rank should be 1, 2, 3, 3, 4 not 1, 2, 3 ,3, 1

Comment: @Hardikgupta   You need `rleid`, updated the data.table solution

Comment: yes, that works. Cannot thank you enough !! Accepting the answer